# Is there any logging of CoolStorage for MonoTouch activity?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, coolstorage

When using CoolStorage as part of a ASP.NET project you can define a log file in the Web.Config where the CoolStorage activity is dumped.

Is there a similar possibility when using CoolStorage for MonoTouch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually very easy:

```
var docFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

CSConfig.Logging = true;
CSConfig.LogFileName = Path.Combine(docFolder,"coolstorage.log");
```

This will log all CoolStorage activity in a file "coolstorage.log" in the documents folder.